# Can I use Likert scale data to do parametric statistical procedures such as linear regression and ANOVA?

Tags: likert, nonparametric

Can I use Likert scale data to do parametric statistical procedures such as linear regression and ANOVA? I've read that you can use Likert data in parametric analysis but in certain circumstances. Which are those? My independent variables are Likert items and my dependent variable is the mean score of a Likert scale. Also, I have 90 samples.

Comment: I assume you're talking about dependent variable.

Comment: It's not recommended because those regression could give you out-of-bound results. If you want to do that, why not just ordinal regression? Also how do you interpret 1.5, 2.567?

Comment: It is common in Usability research to analyse them parametrically and you interpret them as between good and neutral for example but I read that likert scales are something between ordinal and interval. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Both my DV and IVs are Likert bt my DV looks like 4.56 for example so I guess continuous.

Comment: Look at [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175848/28500) and see if it helps clarify the issues. Then you perhaps can make this question a bit more specific to your situation. Pay particular attention to the difference between Likert items and Likert scales, which are based on combinIng multiple Likert items.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question and as I mentioned I have 90 samples and my DV is the mean score of a Likert scale (multiple Likert items). I read that Likert scales should be analysed with non-parametric methods unless when you combine 2 or more questions into an aggregated score which is what I've done I guess. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127543/what-statistical-analysis-should-i-use-for-likert-scale-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good basic statistics to use for ordinal data?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-are-good-basic-statistics-to-use-for-ordinal-data),  

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203/group-differences-on-a-five-point-likert-item, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/general-advice-on-forming-an-index-of-attitude-to-the-environment-from-a-set-of/10522#10522​